# Hyperref only one box around text with line break and not two boxes in twentysecondcv

Tags: hyperref, overleaf, texmaker, box, href

I use the `hyperref` package and the corresponding `\href{}{}` command and would like to adjust the box which is drawn around the text. In more detail, in the picture below you can see a link for address, phone number, and email. The boxes around phone number and email are ok. However, looking at the box for the address one can see that there is a line break and actually there are two boxes and the bottom border of the lower box is acutally crossing the box of the phone number.

[image]

I am aiming for only one box around the address which does not cross the lower box. For illustration see the following image

[image]

or even borders whith some space in between.

When opening the [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/twenty-seconds-curriculum-vitae/kfgsngtymkfj) in overleaf and replacing `\cvaddress{United Kingdom}%address` with `\cvaddress{\href{https://osm.org/go/euut1kjnX?m=}{United Kingdom, this is just for a linebreak}}%address`

one immediately encompasses the problem I am trying to solve, as can be seen here

[image]

To replicate the problem one can use the following code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}} \href{https://osm.org/go/euut1kjnX?m=}{United Kingdom, this is just for a linebreak} \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Of course, just expanding the tabular width is not an option ;)

In more detail, I use the following documentclass `\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcv}` and inserted the following line `\RequirePackage[allbordercolors=red, pdfborder = 0 0 0]{hyperref}` in `twentysecondcv.cls`file. The source code can be found [here.](https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex) Of course, I adapted the source code somehow to obtain a different style, but this does not impact the problem I am facing, as it is present in the source code as well.

If anything is unclear please let me know immediately and I am going to try my best to solve it as soon as possible!

EDIT: I added a MWE and restructured the question slightly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you have done ...

Comment: Thank you for your remark. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to show the code as a MWE directly here due to the fact that the linked template I use does include a .cls file. Usually, I would show the complete LaTeX code where everything is in one document, but I am not familiar in the case of the main file accessing the .cls file. Could you give me a hint how to share the code in this case? Actually, this is the reason why I linked everything (source code and compileable template) and exactly what code to replace.

Comment: A link to the class file and a basic document is often helpful, a full template over link may have some excess content and can be a few more clicks to get the base document to run locally.  I'm guessing in this case you could use `article` class and reproduce the issue with something like `\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}} \href{https://osm.org/go/euut1kjnX?m=}{United Kingdom, this is just for a linebreak} \end{tabular}`

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is very helpful and I am going to include this MWE in my question right away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single link margin you must put the text in its own box:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}} \href{https://osm.org/go/euut1kjnX?m=}{\parbox[t]{4cm}{United Kingdom, this is just for a linebreak}} \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With lualatex it should be theoretically possible to calculate the link area and to use quadpoints to get a combined area, but I'm not aware of any implementation and also imho the support for quadpoints in pdf viewers is rather sketchy.

Comment: The solution can be so simple! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use the [colorlinks=true] option in the hyperref package.  This will give a link without the box.  It is perhaps more elegant.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    
    
    \href{URl}{A general URL \newline on multiple lines that \newline goes nowhere}
    
    Text\cite{Citation} 
    More text\footnote{Footnote}
    
    Details of colour options for links are in section 5.6 of the \href{https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.html#x1-180005.6}{package \newline
         help.} 

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

    \bibitem{Citation}Cited paper

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

(I could not find your source-code easily.)

Comment: This is not an answer in my opinion, as I explicitly ask for the box. I am aware of the possibility to remove the borders. However, the boxes shall draw attention that there is a something/a link when opening the file electronically.

Answer (score 0):

With pdflatex, you can use `\pdflinkmargin` (the experimental `pdflinkmargin` option seems broken):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdflinkmargin0.3pt
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}} \href{https://osm.org/go/euut1kjnX?m=}{United Kingdom, this is just for a linebreak} \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But there is always **two** links (and two boxes) !